# Gradient as Shell's background in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Any idea how I can have a gradient background for a Shell?

I tried defining a LinearGradientBrush on my Shell 's background but that didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Shell.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Shell.Background>

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <!--  FlyoutItem contents here -->
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

Comment: Moving your LinearGradientBrush Background from Shell.Background to the ContentPage.Background works, but, I guess that's not what you're looking for?

Comment: Note the relatively few followers for the tags you have added to your question. I would guess you'll get more eyes on you problem if you add a `.net` tag (or which ever has the most followers). Good luck.

Comment: I have a feeling this is not gonna work with shell, you will have to go ahead and do this on your individual ContentPage's

Comment: Be a bit more precise please, what does "it did not work" mean? What kind of error did you get??

Comment: It does not raise any error. But it does not apply the Brush color.

Comment: And if I tried to color only the contentPage , the color will not be apply to the Top TabBar and the TitleBar.

Comment: @ValèreSETODJI Confirmed that it's a known issue when setting a gradient for Shell.Background  , see [Shell.Background - Gradient does not work #10445](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10445), you can follow the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that it's a known issue when setting a gradient for `Shell.Background` , see [Shell.Background - Gradient does not work #10445](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10445), you can follow the thread.

Fortunately, you can set gradient background separately. You can set the gradient background for shell flyout item if you have a Shell flyout:

```
<Shell.FlyoutBackground>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
</Shell.FlyoutBackground>
```

Also, if you want to set `ShellContent` background to the gradient background, you can add gradient background to the ContentPage's Background property.

```
<ContentPage.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
</ContentPage.Background>
```

Hope this helps!